# Should RESTful URIs expose database primary keys?

Tags: database, web-services, rest, jersey

I'll keep it simple. A Restful URI is something like:

```
example.com/rest/customer/1
```

What is the best common practice for what '1' is. Is it the db generated primary key?

Using a system generated primary key makes me think that it won't be conducive to:

1. Database merges
2. Importing/exporting data

Not using the primary key has its own set of issues. Looking for prevailing thoughts on this topic.

Comment: You should have no issues with that.  The primary key is the (by definition) unique identifier.  Since they won't have access to your database structure, it's a non-issue.

Comment: @prmatta Just wondering if there was anything else you need on this question or if you needed more detail on my answer?

Comment: Ensure the logged in user has authorization to view the URL he is looking at. For example, I should be able to see http://api.bank.com/accounts/666 but not http://api.bank.com/accounts/667 if account 667 does not belong to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect the id to be the primary key as that is how you would identify the record. If you want, and you have one, you could use a [natural primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) e.g. someone's employee id rather than an identity which is a [surrogate key.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)

If your issue is that is is an integer rather than it being the database primary key (and hence I suppose guessable) you could use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) instead. They can be generated on either the client, or server side either in the application or in the DB.

They would help with database merges etc. and they are guaranteed unique.

Answer (score 2):

If you design your RESTful API correctly, the choice of numbering scheme for IDs becomes opaque and irrelevant to your API's consumers.

Applications coded against your API will navigate around it using hyperlinks within your representations, as long as they don't attempt [URI construction](http://morethancoding.com/2011/09/07/uri-construction-give-it-a-rest/). Applying the principles of [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) allows you to use database keys as your resource IDs without worry.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it doesn't matter.

But you should always be returning an href as your unique identifier to the consumer, not just an ID.  If you just return an ID, that means they have to know where the resource lives and combine that information with the ID to make a unique request for the resource.  Returning the href for them eliminates coupling.

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer.. what do you mean return a href from your api? Thanks